# How to know the TFS repository to which a workspace is bound?

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to check to which repository a local is bound to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the owner of the workspace or the computer name, you can use the tf /workspaces command to get detailed information about all the workspaces.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54dkh0y3(VS.80).aspx